# Why Spring loggers are not inherited from org.springframework

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

Off the shelf Spring Boot template: `spring-boot-starter-log4j2`, `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-actuator`.

I'm trying to make log4j2 only log Spring related messages if those are `WARN` and above. For the rest, I would like it to log `DEBUG` and above.

Log4j2 config looks like this:

```
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDERR" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%highlight{[%level]} %logger %message %throwable%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" />

        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDERR"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

For some reason it doesn't work: `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping` appends to `STDERR`. So do `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean`, `org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener`, and many others.

I can manually set level for `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc`, `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet`, `org.springframework.boot.logging` etc. Not sure why it's nessesary though.

Aren't those loggers supposed to bind to the `org.springframework` logger config and use it's `WARN` level?

Log4j diagnostics output:

```
 21:03:58,102 Loaded configuration from /src/SpringBootLoggingTest/log-configuration/log4j2-desktop.xml
 21:03:58,103 Starting LoggerContext[name=42a57993, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6193932a] with configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/src/SpringBootLoggingTest/log-configuration/log4j2-desktop.xml]...
 21:03:58,104 Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/src/SpringBootLoggingTest/log-configuration/log4j2-desktop.xml]
 21:03:58,105 Installed script engines
 21:03:58,120 Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_152, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
 21:03:58,120 PluginManager 'Core' found 110 plugins
 21:03:58,120 PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
 21:03:58,123 Log4j2 ConfigurationScheduler: No scheduled items
 21:03:58,123 PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
 21:03:58,124 Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
 21:03:58,131 PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
 21:03:58,138 PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%highlight{[%level]} %logger %message %throwable%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(/src/SpringBootLoggingTest/log-configuration/log4j2-desktop.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
 21:03:58,139 PluginManager 'Converter' found 44 plugins
 21:03:58,141 Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
 21:03:58,147 ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_ERR", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%highlight{[%level]} %logger %message %throwable%n), name="STDERR", Filter=null)
 21:03:58,147 Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_ERR.false.false
 21:03:58,147 Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
 21:03:58,148 createAppenders(={STDERR})
 21:03:58,149 Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
 21:03:58,154 createLogger(additivity="true", level="WARN", name="org.springframework", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(/src/SpringBootLoggingTest/log-configuration/log4j2-desktop.xml), Filter=null)
 21:03:58,155 Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
 21:03:58,155 createAppenderRef(ref="STDERR", level="null", Filter=null)
 21:03:58,156 Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
 21:03:58,156 createLogger(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", includeLocation="null", ={STDERR}, ={}, Configuration(/src/SpringBootLoggingTest/log-configuration/log4j2-desktop.xml), Filter=null)
 21:03:58,157 Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
 21:03:58,157 createLoggers(={org.springframework, root})
 21:03:58,158 Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/src/SpringBootLoggingTest/log-configuration/log4j2-desktop.xml] initialized
 21:03:58,158 Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/src/SpringBootLoggingTest/log-configuration/log4j2-desktop.xml]
 21:03:58,158 Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/src/SpringBootLoggingTest/log-configuration/log4j2-desktop.xml] OK.
 21:03:58,159 Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-2
 21:03:58,159 Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-2, all resources released: true
 21:03:58,159 Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@654f0d9c OK
 21:03:58,162 Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=42a57993
 21:03:58,163 Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=42a57993,component=StatusLogger
 21:03:58,163 Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=42a57993,component=ContextSelector
 21:03:58,164 Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=42a57993,component=Loggers,name=
 21:03:58,165 Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=42a57993,component=Loggers,name=org.springframework
 21:03:58,165 Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=42a57993,component=Appenders,name=STDERR
 21:03:58,165 LoggerContext[name=42a57993, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6193932a] started OK with configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/src/SpringBootLoggingTest/log-configuration/log4j2-desktop.xml].
 21:03:58,173 AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=CACHED
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below `logger` configuration -

```
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDERR" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDERR" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```